# Where can we find Server.xml in Jboss EAP 6?

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, setting, jboss-eap-6

I am trying some performance tuning and following Jboss performance tuning guide. so i read chapter 3, and i want to turn of Cached Connection Manager. but there is mentioned its configuration is in server.xml. I can't find server.xml anywhere. I am using jboss-eap-6.1 on windows 7. So my question where i will find server.xml or how can i turn off Cached Connection Manager ??

here is the text from tunning guide :

The configuration is in the file server.xml in the directory JBOSS_EAP_DIST/jboss-as/server//deploy/jbossweb.sar. Note that the minimal configuration does not include JBoss Web.
Below is an extract from server.xml in which the CachedConnectionManager is enabled.

```
 <!-- Check for unclosed connections and transaction terminated checks in servlets/jsps.   Important: The dependency on the CachedConnectionManager in META-INF/jboss-service.xml must be  uncommented, too -->

 <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve"  cachedConnectionManagerObjectName="jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager" transactionManagerObjectName="jboss:service=TransactionManager" />
```

To disable the CachedConnectionManager, comment the last three lines, as per the following example:

```
 <!-- Check for unclosed connections and transaction terminated checks in servlets/jsps. Important: The dependency on the CachedConnectionManager in META-INF/jboss-service.xml must be uncommented, too
 <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve" cachedConnectionManagerObjectName="jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager" transactionManagerObjectName="jboss:service=TransactionManager" /> -->
```

Another configuration file also needs to be edited: jboss-beans.xml in the JBOSS_EAP_DIST/jboss-as/server//deploy/jbossweb.sar/META-INF directory. Note that the minimal configuration does not include JBoss Web. This file is used by the micro-container for JBoss Web’s integration with it, and it specifies the connections between the dependent components. In this case, the CachedConnectionManager’s valve is dependent on the transaction manager. So, in order to get rid of the valve properly, we have to remove the dependency information from this configuration file. The pertinent information is at the top of the file, and it looks like the following:

```
 <!-- Only needed if the org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve is enabled in the tomcat server.xml file. -? 
  <depends>jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager</depends>

 <!-- Transaction manager for unfinished transaction checking in the CachedConnectionValve -->
  <depends>jboss:service=TransactionManager</depends>
```

Comment these lines as in the following example:
       jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager -?
        
        jboss:service=TransactionManager</depends>-->

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of EAP you are using has a different file structure from what your configuration guide is telling you. Are you using a configuration guide for JBoss AS 6 to configure JBoss EAP 6? If so, this is the source of your frustration. 
The instructions you have are for what looks like an EAP 5 file structure. 
You can find EAP 6 documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/).

If you are running in standalone mode, your config will be found at ${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml